How to return citations in the response when stream:true in azure openai nodejs chat completions?
I added my own data sources and I am able to get citations when I have streaming disabled. But when I turn on streaming, I do not get an citations in the response.

All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what  problem  you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please  edit  your post to include a  valid question  that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is  on-topic; asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Even I'm facing the same issue with my C# code, please refer to my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78980169/azurechatcitation-citation-is-not-working-with-the-completechatstreamingasync
